# What do inline block divs align to?

Tags: html, css

I thought that every `inline-block` element aligned to a line, according to its individual `vertical-align` value.

But it seems we can get the elements to align according to the position of text inside them.

Let's give an example

```css
.icon-card {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18%;
}

.section1 .icon-card {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.section2 .icon-card {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.section3 .icon-card {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.section1,
.section2,
.section3 {
  width: 260px;
}
```

```html
<div class='section1'>
  <div class='icon-card' style='height:50px'>
  </div>
  <div class='icon-card' style='height:80px'>
  </div>
  <div class='icon-card' style='height:40px'>
  </div>
  <div class='icon-card' style='height:200px'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='section2'>
  <div class='icon-card' style='height:50px'>
  </div>
  <div class='icon-card' style='height:80px'>
  </div>
  <div class='icon-card' style='height:40px'>
  </div>
  <div class='icon-card' style='height:200px'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='section3'>
  <div class='icon-card' style='height:50px'>
    Not
  </div>
  <div class='icon-card' style='height:80px'>
    Quite what
  </div>
  <div class='icon-card' style='height:40px'>
    I
  </div>
  <div class='icon-card' style='height:200px'>
    want
  </div>
</div>
```

(or see https://jsfiddle.net/tqgqrd9a/4/)

In this example we have `section2` and `section3`, that "should" align the same. Why don't they? What is going on?

Ideally, I'd prefer an answer that explains what is going on and tells me where "I should have learned it".

Comment: On a side note, the default value for vertical-align is baseline so you don't need to define them https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain this very well but I understand it, I will give it my best shot

The confusing part here is `vertical-align: baseline` it refer to the baseline of text. In section 2 there is no text so the baseline is just the lowest point on the parent (highest container determines this).

Section 3, since you have text so the boxes line up at the baseline of the text. The baseline of the text is the lowest point of all the text in each box (usually the one with the most amount of text). Each box in section 3 starts where the text starts and since you have height on the boxes, so the text overflows the box and the baseline becomes the lowest point of all the text in each box, in our case box 1 and 2 both have the same number of lines which forms the baseline. If you add more text to one of them you will see the alignment will change as well because the baseline would change due to more text.

If you put `overflow: hidden` on `.icon-card` then section 2 and 3 will be the same because text do not overflow and the baseline is the lowest point on the parent (because text cannot go any lower due to overflow hidden).

Not sure if that was a good explanation but I hope you understand it.

Some docs here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

https://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/

Comment: This works!

But it feels very magical :(

I updated the example to avoid visible overflow. Still, weird alignment without overflow hidden, resonable alignment with overflow hidden

Comment: The key here is when you add text, the baseline becomes the baseline of the text. Each of the boxes starts where the text starts. The only reason the 2nd box starts at the top is because it is defining the baseline since it has the most lines of text. You should copy the html and css from the fiddle into the question to avoid it being closed